# Space Complexity Vs Auxiliary Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, space-complexity

I'm kind of confused between these two terms as for example - the Auxiliary space of merge sort, heapsort and insertion sort is O(1) whereas Space complexity of merge sort, insertion sort, heapsort is O(n).

So, if someone asks me what's the Space complexity of merge sort, heapsort or insertion sort then what should I tell them O(1) or O(n)?

Also, note in case of selection sort, I've read it's Space Complexity is O(1) which is auxiliary space.

So, is it possible the algorithm which uses "in-place computation" and for those algorithms we mention auxiliary space?

Furthermore I know -

Space Complexity = Auxiliary Space + space taken by also wrt input.

Kindly help, thank you!

Comment: you might get better answers on [cs.se]

Comment: Okay!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am working on your answer as we speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at O(n), you need to understand what it means.  It is the "IN THE WORST CASE IT WILL BE N".  I use http://bigocheatsheet.com/ as a point of reference.

When you are looking at space complexity, they will want to know how much is going to be held in memory at a given point in time. This does not include the base structure.  They will want to know the amount of additional space the sort will need in order to execute accordingly.  The difference is structures which need to be entirely in memory.

In regards to your first question, it will at MOST take up N space, but the total amount held in memory for your operations would be O(1).

When you are dealing with SORTS, as you listed above, they are mostly only O(1) because they really just need tmp space to hold things while swaps occur.  Datastructures themselves require MORE space because they have a particular size in memory for whatever manipulations need to occur.

I use the linked website a LOT..

Comment: "Take up N space" -- they could also take up 10N, or 1000N, or 0.001N. Or they could take up 4N + 3 sqrt(N) + 10 log N + 10000. It is some quantity whose largest power of N is 1.

Comment: @fallenreaper Thanks a lot, Sir.